# Let vs. Lambda in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I’m reading “Get programming with Haskell”, from Will Kurt. At the end of Lesson 3, which is about lexical scope, the author writes:

> Using a `let` expression and a lambda function aren’t exactly the same thing under the hood. For example, the following code will cause an error if you try to run it:
>
> ```hs
> counter x = let x = x + 1 in let x = x + 1 in x
> ```
>
> To prove that `let` and lambda aren’t identical, rewrite the counter function exactly as it is here, but use nested lambdas instead of `let`.

Here’s my solution, which works as I expect it to do:

```hs
counterLambda x = (\x -> (\x -> x) (x + 1)) (x + 1)
-- counterLambda 2 == 4
```

**However, as the author suggests, if I run `counter 2` in ghci, it hangs forever** (using GHC 8.8.3).

**What’s happening under the hood?**

PS: It works when I properly name the variables.

```hs
counter x = let a = x + 1 in let b = a + 1 in b
-- counter 2 == 4
```

Comment: In a lamba expression you *map* `x` on `x+1`, whereas with `let x = x+1`, you define `x` as a function where it sums up *itself* and `1`, so you obtain an "infinite loop".

Comment: So the `x` in `x+1` of `let x = ...` refers to the `x` itself. This is often used, for example to make an infinite list, for example with `ones = 1 : ones`.

Comment: This is, in my opinion, not a great example of the difference between let and lambda. A better translation of `let x = e1 in e2` is `(\x -> e2) (fix (\x -> e1))`, and this translation, applied to your example, behaves the same, looping infinitely. A better example of the real difference is ```let x = 1 in (x `div` 1, x / 1)```, where  `x` is used at two different types in the body of the `let`.

Comment: *"what's happening under the hood"* is that `let` in Haskell is recursive, a.k.a. "`letrec`" in other languages; but the usual equivalence given between `(\x -> e2) e1` and `let x = e1 in e2` involves the *non-recursive* `let`, which Haskell lacks. IOW this example / explanation in the book is really no good. but there *is* a difference in Haskell between lambda and let, which DanielWagner's comment illustrates. *Haskell*'s `let` binding's type is polymorphic, but the binding's type from lambda function application is monomorphic: ``(\x -> (x `div` 1, x / 1)) 1`` doesn't work while let does.

Comment: and in case you were wondering, `(fix (\x -> e1)` is another way of writing `let x = e1 in x` (except for that polymorphism issue, probably).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In both the lambdas and the `let`s, each `x` shadows the one before. The difference is in the scope of the shadow. The scope of a lambda argument is limited to the lambda, but the scope of a let binding is the entire `let ... = ... in ...` structure, thus `let x = x + 1` defines `x` in terms of *itself*, while `(\x -> x) (x + 1)` shadows `x` in terms of the *unshadowed `x`*. Let me demonstrate the shadow scopes of each of your implementations by adding a number to each `x`:

```
counterLambda x0 = (\x1 -> (\x2 -> (\x3 -> x3) x2) (x1 + 1)) (x0 + 1)

counter       x0 = let x1 = x1 + 1 in let x2 = x2 + 1 in x2
```

Now it should be clear why these are different. In the lambda version, `x1` is assigned `x0 + 1`, while in the `let` version, `x1` is assigned `x1 + 1`, which does not terminate.